# How to integrate facebook share in mobile browser and call a function if share is success?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to share my website onto facebook and perform a function if the facebook share is success.

I have used Facebook Javascript SDK with display : 'popup'. The share functionality is working fine but opens my page in a new tab which is causing problem executing my function. The issue is only for mobile browser. It is working as expected in desktop

Here is my code:

```
FB.ui({
       display: 'popup',
       method:  'share',
       href: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/mypage',
       },
       function(response) {
                if (response != 'undefined' && response instanceof Array) {
                    loadAutoPopup_thanksfb();  
                } 
       });
});
```

I tried With display : 'iframe' method, but it did not solve my problem
Please help in return to same page after facebook share for mobile browser

Comment: I cannot use url redirection method as I need to call a function if facebook share is success

Comment: There is no way any more for you to know whether the share was actually made. Facebook removed that, because it was abused too much by shady developers trying to "force" a share, or reward users for it in any way - which is not allowed.

Comment: It is working fine in desktop. Issue is in mobile browser

Comment: Why would you need to know whether the share happened? Let me repeat, if you plan on forcing it or rewarding users for it in any way, you would be in violation of FB developer policy.